# Hot to force QnAMaker to throw a LowScoreHandler or

Tags: c#, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

Hi guys is there a way for me to train QNAmaker to throw none or a NoMatchHandler?
I have some questions that was incorrectly answered by QNAmaker, I need to train the QNAmaker to throw a low score so that it will then be forwarded to luis. I already have this set of codes that pretty much work well when QNAmaker does not have an answer, but I still have to refine my QNAMaker training.

```
  public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.Forward(new RootLuisDialog(), DialogsCompleted, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I tried using the train and test ui of the qna maker but apparently all it can do is to throw a No good match found in the KB response when you choose none of the above as the option. is there another way for me to force the qnamaker to throw a no match? so that my nomatchhandler method will fire?

[image]

Comment: This has the C tag on it and is missing the correct language tag (C++ ?).

Comment: done with the edit on correct tag.